# How to access view property from controller in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

I have a method in controller where I need to access a view property and set it value. How to achieve this in emberjs?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rerender a view that depends on a controller's property, just bound it in your template

```
{{#view "myView" foo=controllerProperty}}
    {{propertyThatDependsOnFoo}}
{{/view}}


App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    foo: null, // initialized in template
    ...
    propertyThatDependsOnFoo: function() {
        ...
    }.property("foo")
});
```

Then in your controller just change `controllerProperty`, automatically this will be reflected in your view.

Comment: Shouldn't it be as follows?
    `{{#view "myView" fooBinding=controllerProperty}}
        {{view.propertyThatDependsOnFoo}}
    {{/view}}`